# Solving inequality with parameter(algorithm of solving)

Tags: inequality

I want to solve this Inequality:

$4*x(1-x) >= 1/n$ ,where n is positive number. In usual situations without parameter a solution is clear(put everything on the left side, s.t RHS is 0). But how to solve this one?

Wolframalpha give the following solution:

$x>= sqrt(1/n) + 1$

$x>= 1 - sqrt(1/n)$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Do not be afraid of parameter. Let me follow your instruction to find the solution.

Put everything on the left hand side.

$$4x(1-x)-\frac1n \geq 0$$

$$-4x^2+4x-\frac1n \geq 0$$
Multiply by negative:
$$4x^2-4x+\frac1n \leq 0$$

Notice that function $f(x) = 4x^2-4x+\frac1n \leq 0$ is a convex function.

- Suppose the root of the equation $4x^2-4x+\frac1n=0$ are $r_1, r_2$ where $r_1 > r_2$. Then the solution is $r_2 \le x \leq r_1$.
- Suppose the root of the equation $4x^2-4x+\frac1n=0$ are $r_1, r_2$ where $r_1 = r_2$. Then the solution is $x= r_1$.
- Suppose there is no real root, there is no real solution.

You should sketch picture to understand quadratic function.

Given these information, do you think your initial solution is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at the graph of $y = 4 x (1-x)$.  You want $y \ge 1/n$.